# Unable to uninstall libglib2.0-0 from Software Center

Tags: debian, package-management, glib

I have a fresh install of Debian 6.0.5 (i386) on VMware Player. I was trying to install libglib2.0-0 using this command:

```
sudo aptitude install libglib2.0-0
```

Unfortunately, I don't remember the exact output from the terminal but I remember there were 0 bytes installed or something. I'm guessing it didn't install correctly, so I want to remove it and try installing from the Software Center instead. However, when I click on remove, it just "greys out" and nothing happens. How do I uninstall it? Is there a command that could remove it from the terminal?

EDIT: The output of:

```
dpkg -l 'libglib2.0-0'

root@vmware:/home/mohamed# dpkg -l 'libglib2.0-0'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version        Description
+++-==============-==============-============================================
ii  libglib2.0-0   2.24.2-1       The GLib library of C routines
root@vmware:/home/mohamed#
```

Comment: It returned a message saying it "couldn't find package libglib2.0" but that there were other packages with similar names like "libglib2.0-0-refdbg".

Comment: It might be installed already, show output of `dpkg -l 'libglib2.0-0'` (put it in your question area, don't use a comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the output of `dpkg -l 'libglib2.0-0'`, the `ii` means the package is installed, and configured.

Since the package is downloaded and installed already, so now more network traffic, that's why the software installer told you 0 bytes downloaded.

To remove the package, use `apt-get remove libglib2.0-0`. glib is linked with lots of packages, you're likely to ruin your system after this. You can't remove it from software center, because it has other dependencies, e.g important system binaries.

Comment: Since it installed correctly, why am I not able to uninstall the program from Software Center? Is there a command to remove it from terminal that I could try?

Comment: @MohamedAbobakr updated answer

Comment: Oh, so that's why it won't remove it. Thanks for clearing that up warl0ck!